# tika parser get error : Problem with writing the data, class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.MultipartBody

Tags: apache-tika

After that we upgrade to java 11 our tika parser 0.7 stop to work, parser raise error:
**
Failed to add extensions to 000000001_0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.tika.parser.Parser is not an ImageIO SPI class
at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.checkClassAllowed(ServiceRegistry.java:722)
at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.lookupProviders(ServiceRegistry.java:207)
**

In java 8 works successfully

I up the version to 1.24.1 (from 1.19 it must support java 11) and all needed jars as cfx*

```
   127509 Aug 26 13:52 javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar
   346445 Aug 26 14:23 cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.4.0.jar
   382008 Aug 26 14:24 cxf-rt-transports-http-3.4.0.jar
  1414830 Aug 26 14:24 cxf-core-3.4.0.jar
   696050 Aug 26 14:27 cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.4.0.jar
   187625 Aug 26 14:30 cxf-rt-rs-client-3.4.0.jar
    59386 Aug 26 14:32 cxf-rt-rs-service-description-3.4.0.jar
   365552 Aug 26 19:57 commons-compress-1.8.1.jar
   276413 Aug 27 10:29 commons-io-2.7.jar
    53820 Aug 27 10:48 commons-cli-1.4.jar
   284220 Aug 27 10:53 commons-lang-2.6.jar
   219146 Aug 27 10:55 javax.mail-api-1.6.2.jar
 47929542 Aug 27 11:59 tika-bundle-1.24.1.jar
   708157 Aug 27 11:59 tika-core-1.24.1.jar
  1336431 Aug 27 11:59 tika-parsers-1.24.1.jar
    39881 Aug 27 12:00 tika-translate-1.24.1.jar
    18069 Aug 27 12:01 tika-serialization-1.24.1.jar
    35100 Aug 27 12:01 tika-xmp-1.24.1.jar
```

but now I get same error as:

```
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Problem with writing the data, class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.MultipartBody, ContentType: multipart/form-data
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.reportMessageHandlerProblem(AbstractClient.java:846)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.writeBody(AbstractClient.java:529)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient$BodyWriter.doWriteBody(WebClient.java:1223)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient$AbstractBodyWriter.handleMessage(AbstractClient.java:1222)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.doRunInterceptorChain(AbstractClient.java:703)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:1086)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:932)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:901)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:364)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.post(WebClient.java:373)
at org.apache.tika.parser.journal.GrobidRESTParser.parse(GrobidRESTParser.java:81)
at org.apache.tika.parser.journal.JournalParser.parse(JournalParser.java:60)
at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
... 50 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242
```

Our code to parse online documents:

```
        try {
            ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
            parser.parse(in, handler, metadata, new ParseContext());

            return handler.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.warn("Problem in getting the content of "+filePath);
            throw new RuntimeException("Problem in getting the content of "+filePath, e);
        }
        catch (SAXException e) {
            logger.warn("Problem in parsing the content of "+filePath);
            throw new RuntimeException("Problem in parsing the content of "+filePath, e);
        }
        catch (TikaException e) {
            logger.warn("Problem in parsing the content of "+filePath);
            throw new RuntimeException("Problem in parsing the content of "+filePath, e);
        }
```

Comment: Are you using Grobid?

Comment: I'm use AutoDetectParser , but it start JournalParser. I'm not define Grobid anywhere. I need additional configuration? or I may tell not use it?

Comment: Do you have a custom Tika Config file? That doesn't look like the default config is all, I think you might have (accidentally?) enabled grobid

Comment: I start up from Tika 0.7 , there is no configuration file. Now I try understand how to config it so that not WebCall process,,